# How to open bridge IP address in web browser?

Tags: networking, browser, vmware, bridge

I have a few virtual machines that are set up on bridge network. One of this virtual machines (HDP sandbox) has the web ui and I wanna use it but it's IP is not opened on the browser. What's should i do?

Comment: If you would like to miss a negative voting, please tell the reason for being bad question.

Comment: It isn't a programming question so it simply isn't on-topic here. It might be on-topic at [su]

Answer (score 0):

As i understand it,your vm has a web server.if so,check the status of apache service.If it is not running,you have to start it.

```
service apache2 status
service apache2 start
```

after you run the commands above(command may be different due to linux distro),
enter ip address into the web browser.

also,you must be sure that HDP services are running.